# mvc session timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using mvc form authenticate. After session Timeout it's automatically redirecting to login page.

How can I redirect to some other page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `loginUrl` attribute of the `authentication/forms` element in your web.config to the URL that you want to redirect anonymous users to when they attempt to access a restricted resource.